# Creating Formatted Arrays Fortran...End of File Error

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm having this error pop up and I'm not sure this is happening.  I'm trying to read in the following data:

```
1   0000  1234
2   0032  8383
3   1201  3983
4   1234  9292
5   4567  9202
6   7890  8382
7   2324  9383
```

skipping the first 4 lines, and reading the integers in the second column in separate array (so have one array produce 4567, 7890, 2324, and the other producing 9202, 8382, and 9383).  Below is the code I have:

```
Program test
Implicit None
integer :: i
integer, parameter :: &
 m=7, &    !total number of line
 n=4, &    !line to skip
 p=3      !lines to read
integer,dimension(m)::arr, arr2   !file to read

open(12,file='something.txt',status='old')
10 format (T5, I4)
do i=1,n
read(12,10)arr(i)
end do
do i=1,p
read(12,10)arr(i)
write(*,*)arr(i)
end do

20 format (T11, I4)
do i=1,n
read(12,20)arr2(i)
end do
do i=1,p
read(12,20)arr2(i)
write(*,*)arr2(i)
end do
End Program test
```

The first array will read in correctly, but when it reaches to the second one, an end of file error occurs at line 22 comes up.  I'm new to Fortran so I'm not quite sure why this is coming up.

Comment: You're possibly just missing a `rewind` between the array readings.  That said, if I were writing this I'd do it in a single pass of the file and not use `T` editing.

Comment: declare a dummy integer (say `d`) and read each line list directed as `read(12,*)d,arr(i),arr2(i)`

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `read` in a formatted file, the program reads the whole line and moves forward.

Basically after you have read in `arr` completely, the pointer points to the end of the file, and that is where the read to `arr2` would start.

You can do one of two things:

1. `rewind` the file between the two reads.
2. read both arrays at the same time.

The second solutions is better because you're not reading the file twice. Here's an example:

```
program test

    implicit none
    integer :: i
    integer, parameter :: &
        m=7, &
        n=4, &
        p=m-n

    integer :: arr(p), arr2(p)

    open(unit=12, file='something.txt', action='READ', status='OLD')

    do i = 1, n
        read(12, "()")
    end do

    do i = 1, p
        read(12, '(4X, I4, 2X, I4)') arr(i), arr2(i)
    end do

    close(12)

    print*, arr
    print*, arr2

end program test
```

I personally would do two other things:

1. declare a dummy integer variable, and then read using

   ```
   read(12, *) dummy, arr(i), arr2(i)
   ```

   instead of mucking around with formats in a `read` statement.
2. For all file i/o I would always check the outcome of the `iostat` parameter to make sure everything worked as intended.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this!  This makes a lot more sense now!  Additional question: if I were to read the file twice, what we been better between the two solutions you mentioned?

Comment: Again: File I/O is much slower than memory i/o, so I'd advise against it. That said, if you were to add a `rewind(12)` just before the line `20 format (T11, I4)` line in your code, it should work.